# how to display top images based on ratings done by the user in meteor

Tags: meteor, rating

I have built a site using meteor framework where user logs in and upload pics. The pics can be voted by a rating system. In the home page i want to display the highly rated images in descending order of rating.

Also I want user to rate only once from his IP address.

Comment: Hi Man U - What have you tried so far? Please read how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Search and research. You can search the SO site using tag put [meteor]  in the search to see what you can find. For example, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33129171/4606130 for possible leads.

Comment: I have no issues in uploading the images in meteor. But my problem is I have to display those images based on the user rating. Can anyone help ?

Comment: There are several tutorials related to voting systems implemented in Meteor. You should describe a specific problem you are facing and describe what you have tried and where you got stuck. You should think hard about how you want to apply the IP restriction. There are several approaches, including storing all IPs in a ratings collection on the server (not very scalable and not very useful when a user changes IP address), use a cookie (can be easily bypassed) or only allow registered users to vote.

Comment: Is it possible to display the images based on rating they received in descending order ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pics.find({}, {sort: {rating: -1}});
```

Will return all documents from Pics collection in descending order. You can use it with a helper, like so:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    pictures: function() {
        return Pics.find({}, {sort: {rating: -1}});
    }
});
```

For rating permissions, take a look at Atmosphere's website. There you can find some useful packages by searching for "persistent session", that would be a better approach than restrict by IP as MasterAM has mentioned in the comments.